# Why can't there be multi-state in DFA?

Tags: regex, dfa

My question is , can state3 also be named state2, or in general. Why can we name our states with same names.
For the expression `ab+a*a`
First state takes 'a'.
then it will either go state2/state3.[image]

Comment: I don't get it.  Why do you want your states to have the same names?

Comment: I just started this course. From what I understand, the string will go to either state2/state3 , so wouldn't it just be simply named state2 for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite state machine is defined to contain (among other things) a *set* of states, so it makes sense for each state to be uniquely identified. The naming of states has nothing whatsoever to do with the order they might be hit.

It's not uncommon for an FSM to involve a cycle. An example would be an FSM to accept a binary string with an even number of 0's, represented by the state table below:

```
Input --> | 0      | 1      |
\/--State |        |        |
----------|--------|--------|
state0    | state1 | state0 |
state1    | state0 | state1 |

States: {state0, state1}
Start state: state0
Accepting states: {state0}
```

In that case, the machine might move from `state0` to `state1` and back many times. The machine's complexity would explode to infinity if we had to have a new state every time.

Answer (score 1):

you can name your states whatever you want so long as they are uniquely identifiable.

If the states aren't different, than they shouldn't be 2 separate states in the first place

---

your particular example doesn't have any `or`-ing, so your regex will never use a DFA that branches like that.

But let's say you had a regex like

`a(bb | cc)`, which can match `abb` or `acc`

`ab` and `ac` are different states, and they have to be distinguished from one-another and the output from them leads to different conclusions.

If you were at `ab` and you got a `c` than you would have to go back to the start, but If you were in the state `ac` and got `c` than you would proceed to `acc` and finish.